# How can I modify configuration of the Kafka testcontainers image?

Tags: apache-kafka, testcontainers

I use the Kafka testcontainers image in my local testing setup.

I want to update configs for Kafka to match my deployment envionment. In particluar, I want to disable `auto.create.topics.enable` [property](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_auto.create.topics.enable) which looks like defaulted to `true`?

I do not want to override the image and I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: testcontainers Kafka is built on top of `confluent-kafka` image and therefore supports passing the same env variables.

I found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/cgswong/confluent-kafka) (this one is unofficial) that the original image supports `KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE` env var.

So it is possible to do something like:

```
    public static KafkaContainer kafka =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.3"))
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "false");
```